# Create an enumeration of one

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

If I want an empty enumeration, I can call `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`. But what if I want to convert a scalar type to an enumeration?

Normally I'd write `new List<string> {myString}` to pass `myString` to a function that accepts `IEnumerable<string>`. Is there a more LINQ-y way?

Comment: what do you mean by more LINQ-y? LINQ is query and you are creating something. Enumerable != linq

Comment: @msarchet: Well, `Enumerable` is in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
var justOne = Enumerable.Repeat(value, 1);
```

Or just an array of course:

```
var singleElementArray = new[] { value };
```

The array version is mutable of course, whereas `Enumerable.Repeat` isn't.

Comment: Array of  singleton anonymous type is so much LINQier than singleton List of int because it's got anonymous!

Comment: @sq33G: That's not using an anonymous type. It's using an implicitly typed array - completely different.

Comment: My bad. Still beats the simple List in the test of LINQiness.

Answer (score 3):

There is, but it's less efficient than using a List or Array:

```
// an enumeration containing only the number 13.
var oneIntEnumeration = Enumerable.Repeat(13, 1);
```

Comment: Why is this less efficient than using a List or Array?

Comment: @phoog: just in terms of execution speed, the construction of an single-element array is faster (though very, very small difference).  That said, the `Enumerable.Repeat()` does have the benefit of giving you something that's read-only of course.

Comment: @phoog: for 1 million creations `var oneIntArray = new int[] { 13 };` is 3 ms and `var oneIntEnumeration = Enumerable.Repeat(13, 1);` is 15 ms (all times on my machine of course).  So that's VERY minor per call difference and probably just a micro-optimization.  I'd use whichever you like best, both work.

Comment: I really liked your blog post on this: http://blackrabbitcoder.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/12/08/c-fundamentals-returning-zero-or-one-item-as-ienumerablelttgt.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the shortest form is

```
var sequence = new[] { value };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your own extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T item)
    {
         yield return item;
    }
}
```

Now I haven't done that, and now that I know about Enumerable.Repeat, I probably never will (learn something new every day).  But I *have* done this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MakeEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
{
     return items;
}
```

And this, of course, works if you call it with a single argument.  But maybe there's something like this in the framework already, that I haven't discovered yet.